# Upgrade windows 10 to the latest version

Tags: windows

after a virus attack (that encrypted all of my files) I had to format all whole PC good friend of mine did the whole job but forgot to tell me he's using an Enterprise edition. I've tried to upgrade form windows 10, 1607 to the latest version via Windows 10 Update Assistant but I'm getting a error message: "Contact your system administrator to upgrade windows server or enterprise editions".

My friend, giving excuses why to stay with that version (1607) and he's not willing to help me change that so I can do it by myself.

Can you please tell me how to do that without reformat my PC? I've tried to search the whole internet but I couldn't find any help..

Thanks!

Anthony

Comment: It’s as simple as booting to the installation media, delete the partitions on the disk, and install Windows on the unallocated partition

Comment: I would say there's a pretty good chance that your friend installed a pirated copy of Windows Enterprise on your system. There's no telling what kind of malicious garbage could be hidden inside of that. Get rid of it. Format your PC and install Windows 10 from a proper ISO downloaded from Microsoft's official site.

Comment: It's a legal instillation, the're no other solution like some kind of an upgrade?

Comment: Your friend just happened to have an Enterprise license?

Comment: yes, but he's refusing to give it to me..

Comment: Because it's not legit. Trust me. But anyway, in the time you've been trying to figure this all out you could have already reinstalled Windows by now.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is install windows 10 Home or Pro with a valid license from scratch. That way you can upgrade to a later version for free without much hastle.

I would definitely NOT stay with version 1607. The longer you keep an old version in use, the slower windows becomes because it is being patched with windows updates. The beauty of newer upgrades is that you get a new baseline with no updates per upgrade, and update from there, making windows much more responsive.

Enterprise licenses are very very expensive, so it is very likely your friend uses a pirated copy.